# add_cap not working

Tags: php, users, capabilities

Need to add a cap for the role editor, to grant them acess to a sub menu, but for some reason its not working.

This is the sub-menu:

public function submenu_apps_init() {

```
    $news_push = new Fieldmanager_TextField( 'Prefixo do push das notícias', array(
        'input_type'  => 'text',
        'description' => 'O prefixo escolhido será utilizado no push das notícias para a app',
        'attributes'  => array(
            'maxlength' => 40,
        )
    ) );

    $fm = new Fieldmanager_Group( array(
        'name'     => 'app-items',
        'children' => array(
            'news_push'     => $news_push,
        )
    ) );
    $fm->activate_submenu_page();
```

And this is how im adding the cap:

```
function add_theme_caps() {
            // gets the author role
            $role = get_role( 'editor' );

            // This only works, because it accesses the class instance.
            $role->add_cap( 'news_push', true );
        }
        add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_theme_caps' );

    }
```

Can someone help me out, and point out what im doing wrong?